# ListItem in material UI reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to use custom buttons for ListItem with children. I am able to change the open button using rightIconButton props of ListItem, but unable to change it after toggling. I have tried using righToggle props of ListItem, but still, it's not working.

```
<ListItem 
  style={{height: 46}} 
  nestedListStyle={{padding: 0}}
  key={key}
  open={this.checkOpenMenu()}
  primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
  primaryText='test'
  rightIconButton = {
    <IconButton style={{}}><img src={baseUrl + "/open.svg" } alt="More" />
    </IconButton>}
  rightToggle = {
    <IconButton style={{}}><img src={baseUrl + "/close.svg" } alt="More" />
    </IconButton>}
  nestedItems={children}
/>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer

```
<ListItem 
  style={{height: 46}} 
  nestedListStyle={{padding: 0}}
  key={key}
  open={this.checkOpenMenu()}
  primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
  primaryText='test'
  rightIconButton = { condition ? <IconButton><img src={baseUrl + "/close.svg" } alt="More" /></IconButton> : <IconButton><img src={baseUrl + "/open.svg" } alt="More" /></IconButton>}
  nestedItems={children}
/>);
```